# Firebase上のデータベースをMatLabで取得する方法

Tags: firebase, matlab

現在、MatLabでFirebase上のデータベースの処理を行いたいと思っていますが、
どのようにMatLab上で記述することによりFirebaseのデータベースを取得、更新することができるでしょうか。MatLabは全く無知で申し訳ありませんが、検索しても具体的な方法が見つからなかったため質問させていただきます。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase DatabaseにはREST APIが提供されているので MATLABからでもHTTP Requestでデータベースへの読み書きが可能です。

詳細はドキュメントを確認してみてください。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。REST APIを用いて、実際にMATLABでjsonデータの取得を行えました。ありがとうございました！